# How do ffmpeg child processes differ on windows and linux? ytdl

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg, child-process, ytdl

This class method works on linux but does not work on windows. Why is that? ytdl is a node module called ytdl-core. This is almost line for line what they used in their documentation.

https://github.com/fent/node-ytdl-core/blob/master/example/ffmpeg.js

The biggest difference in my code vs theirs is that I convert the mkv file to an mp4 before closing the process.

I have been looking around the internet and I cannot seem to find anyone with this issue. I am new to child processes and ffmpeg.

```
static mp4 = async (url, videoQuality, destination) => {
    try {
      const videoInfo = this.#getVideoInfo(url);
      const videoTitle = (await videoInfo).title;

    const tracker = {
      start: Date.now(),
      audio: { downloaded: 0, total: Infinity },
      video: { downloaded: 0, total: Infinity },
      merged: { frame: 0, speed: '0x', fps: 0 },
    };
    
    // Get audio and video streams
    const audio = ytdl(url, { quality: 'highestaudio' })
      .on('progress', (_, downloaded, total) => {
        tracker.audio = { downloaded, total };
      });
    
    
      const video = ytdl(url, { quality: videoQuality })
      .on('progress', (_, downloaded, total) => {
        tracker.video = { downloaded, total };
      })
      .on('error', (error) => {
        console.error('(mp4) An error occurred when attempting to pipe the video stream:', error);
      });

    // Start the ffmpeg child process
    const mkvProcess = cp.spawn(ffmpeg, [
      // Remove ffmpeg's console spamming
      '-loglevel', '8', '-hide_banner',
      // Redirect/Enable progress messages
      '-progress', 'pipe:3',
      // Set inputs
      '-i', 'pipe:4',
      '-i', 'pipe:5',
      // Map audio & video from streams
      '-map', '0:a',
      '-map', '1:v',
      // Keep encoding
      '-c:v', 'copy',
      // Define output file
      `${__dirname}/temp/temp.mkv`,
    ], {
      windowsHide: true,
      stdio: [
        /* Standard: stdin, stdout, stderr */
        'inherit', 'inherit', 'inherit',
        /* Custom: pipe:3, pipe:4, pipe:5 */
        'pipe', 'pipe', 'pipe',
      ],
    });
    mkvProcess.on('close', () => {
      const titleQuality = this.nativeMp4VideoQualityFormats[videoQuality];
      const mp4Process = cp.spawn(ffmpeg, ['-i',`${__dirname}/temp/temp.mkv`,'-c','copy',`${destination}`]);
      
      mp4Process.on('close', () => {
        if (fs.existsSync(`${__dirname}/temp/temp.mkv`)){
          try {
            fs.unlinkSync(`${__dirname}/temp/temp.mkv`);
          }
          catch (error){
            console.log(error)
          }
        };
      })
      mp4Process.on('exit', (code, signal) => {
        if (code !== 0) {
          console.error(`(mp4) The ffmpeg process exited with code ${code} and signal ${signal}.`);
        }
      })
    });
    mkvProcess.on('exit', (code, signal) => {
      if (code !== 0) {
        console.error(`(mkv) The ffmpeg process exited with code ${code} and signal ${signal}.`);
      }
    });
    // Link streams
    // FFmpeg creates the transformer streams and we just have to insert / read data
    mkvProcess.stdio[3].on('data', chunk => {
    
      const lines = chunk.toString().trim().split('\n');
      const args = {};
      for (const l of lines) {
        const [key, value] = l.split('=');
        args[key.trim()] = value.trim();
      }
      tracker.merged = args;
    });
    audio.pipe(mkvProcess.stdio[4]);
    video.pipe(mkvProcess.stdio[5]);
    return true;

    }
    catch {
      console.error('(mp4) An error occurred when attempting to download the video.')
      return false;
    }
  }
```

Comment: What happens when you run the code on Windows? Does it give any output?